# log4j for my class only

Tags: scala, logging, apache-kafka

I'm trying to set up a log4j logger for the first time, but it started to ignore my config it seems.

I get the dreaded `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger` warning.

I want this to log to console & to a file for ease of debugging and deployment.

```
log4j.rootCategory=FATAL, util_kafka_console, util_kafka_file
log4j.logger.com.me.kafka=DEBUG

log4j.additivity.com.me.kafka=false



#I set this on the JVM to direct logs to specific location & file

filename=please_specify_log_location.log
my_kafka.logs.dir=log

log4j.appender.util_kafka_console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.util_kafka_console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.util_kafka_console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} \t %x %c [%M] (%L) - %m%n


log4j.appender.util_kafka_file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} \t %x %c [%M] (%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.File=${my_kafka.logs.dir}/${filename}
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.MaxBackupIndex=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must define a rootCategory as

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, util_kafka_console, util_kafka_file
```

**EDITED**

below is the working version

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, util_kafka_console, util_kafka_file
log4j.logger.com.ssll=DEBUG

log4j.additivity.com.me.kafka=false



#I set this on the JVM to direct logs to specific location & file

filename=please_specify_log_location.log
my_kafka.logs.dir=log

log4j.appender.util_kafka_console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.util_kafka_console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.util_kafka_console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} \t %x %c [%M] (%L) - %m%n


log4j.appender.util_kafka_file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} \t %x %c [%M] (%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.File=${my_kafka.logs.dir}/${filename}
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.MaxBackupIndex=2
```

Comment: but I don't want other underlying classes to spew debug logs into my logs

Comment: you can control this by `log4j.category.your.special.package=DEBUG` and set `log4j.rootCategory=FATAL, util_kafka_console, util_kafka_file`

Comment: The configuration file must have a name as `log4j.properties` and keeped in the class path root folder

Comment: I package it in my application (it's in the resource folder) and it's named log4j.properties

Comment: Double check your packaged file/jar/war, if there realy exists your expected file, maybe a duplicated configuration file over write it or it just absent

Comment: doublechecked, it's in there. for good measure, placed a copy of the .properties file in the jar's location too. still shows no logs and  `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.me.kafka.Producer$).´

Comment: you miss `layout` in this `log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.layout.ConversionPattern=...`

Comment: what do you mean? it's in there 
`log4j.appender.util_kafka_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`

Comment: see the edited answer, I think you can find the difference

Comment: I think I have found my issue. It's acutually in `filename=please_specify_log_location.log` when I set that in the -D flag, it want to use the file I want to log to as the config file... I have used a word that's reserved!